# Почему в браузере открывается apache2 вместо nginx?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, apache2, vagrant

Устанавливаю ubuntu-18.04 на виртуалке  с помощью vagrant.

Содержимое vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-18.04"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.synced_folder "C:/vagrant/projects", "/var/www"
end
```

На эту же виртуалку ставлю nginx, php, mysql.
apache2 в автозагрузке отключен. 
Вот что показывает `systemctl status nginx`

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   <b>Active: active (running) </b>since Mon 2018-08-06 19:55:03 UTC; 5min ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 1519 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/ngin
  Process: 1528 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/
  Process: 1523 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited,
 Main PID: 1531 (nginx)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 1135)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─1531 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
           └─1533 nginx: worker process
```

Почему когда я открываю в браузере localhost:8080 я вижу стандартную заглушку apache2, вместо ожидаемого приветствия nginx?  Как это исправить?

Делаю это первый раз, так что прошу понять и простить :)

UPDATE: 
Содержимое `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:`

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

Comment: Ну вы посмотрите в `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` куда там `root` указывает. Вероятно, туда же, где apache дефолтный сайт создал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache при установке создаёт папку **/var/www/html** и создаёт там файл **index.html**.

В настройках nginx у вас дефолтный конфиг смотрит именно туда:

```
root /var/www/html;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
```

Поменяйте путь `root /var/www/html;` на тот, который вы хотите, или замените содержимое файла **/var/www/html/index.html**