# Не могу убрать дефолтную страницу Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page

Tags: wordpress, apache2

Установил wordpress-5.3-ru_RU на базе сервера Apache2.

Но не могу убрать эту страницу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

прочитал два ответа, на примерно похожий вопрос. [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/865228/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-apache2-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-nginx) и [тут](https://qna.habr.com/q/475818)

Поначалу я вообще не понял что происходит, после понял но было уже поздно ;_; ,прошло не меньше недели после установки и я даже забыл где лежат установленные файлы (с которыми машина работает).
А также где лежит главная страница вордпресса, я также не знаю.

Apache при установке создаёт папку /var/www/html и создаёт там файл index.html.

> В настройках nginx у вас дефолтный конфиг смотрит именно туда:
>
> root /var/www/html;
>
> Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
>
> Поменяйте путь root /var/www/html; на тот, который вы хотите, или
>   замените содержимое файла /var/www/html/index.html

**Как узнать, где лежит главная страница вордпресса ??**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Настрой в apache приоритеты DirectoryIndex

```
DirectoryIndex index.php, index.html
```

Comment: Это надо в директории `/var/www/html` открыть файл index.html , и там прописать `DirectoryIndex index.php, index.html` , так ?? Я правильно расписал алгоритм ??

Comment: Это надо настроить аппач. Т.е. в его конфиге. Найти и исправить на то, что я показал.

Comment: я вас не понял. Что надо сделать ???  _либо можете пожалуйста удалить ибо это не ответ, а скрытая компетенция как бы часть ответа, но не ответ._ **Это очень важно ибо я нацелен на результат а не вечные диалоги.**

Comment: Это вполне ответ. Существует два способа настройки апача: один через конфиги сервера (этот способ SeVlad вам рекомендует), второй через правку файлов .htacess в каталоге /var/www или где у вас wwwroot (если такое предусмотрено). Вполне возможно, вам стоит ознакомиться с этой темой или задать отдельный вопрос, где и как правятся настройки апача. Скрытые компетенции у всех разные, кто-то может потребовать и объяснить, как файлы на хостинге по ftp править. Пожалуйста, старайтесь задавать конкретные атомарные вопросы. Пока у вас не атомарный вопрос но атомарный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

В общем надо было вызвать команду

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf
```

И заменить строку

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm
```

на

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

теперь всё содержимое файла dir.conf выглядит так :

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html 
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

после сохранения файла надо перегрузить  сервер:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

---

[image]